# NSInternalInconsistencyException error within TableView Accessory?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5, uitableview

I'm attempting to add an accessory (checked/unchecked) to this tableview, and for some reason xCode is telling me that something is wrong with this line: **[item setObject:cell forKey:@"StrainTableCell"];**

**The console throws me this error:**

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'*

Does anyone know why? See code snippets below.

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PickerViewController.h"


@interface PickerResultsTableViewController : UITableViewController  {

    NSIndexPath *currentDetailPath;
    bool loaded;


    NSArray *Strains;
    NSArray *searchResults;
    NSMutableArray *dataArray;
    NSMutableData *data;

}

- (IBAction)backbuttonpressed: (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *favoritesArrayset;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *PickerTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *searchResults;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableSet * favoritesArray;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    static NSString *strainTableIdentifier = @"StrainTableCell";

    StrainTableCell *cell = (StrainTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strainTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)


        cell = [[StrainTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strainTableIdentifier];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;


    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StrainTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];



        if (tableView == PickerTableView) {
            NSLog(@"Using the search results");

            cell.titleLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
            cell.descriptionLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Description"];
            cell.ratingLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Rating"];
            cell.ailmentLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ailment"];
            cell.actionLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Action"];
            cell.ingestLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ingestion"];

            NSLog(@"%@", searchResults);



        } else {
            NSLog(@"Using the FULL LIST!!");
            cell.titleLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
            cell.descriptionLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Description"];
            cell.ratingLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Rating"];
            cell.ailmentLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ailment"];
            cell.actionLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Action"];
            cell.ingestLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ingestion"];

        }


    NSMutableDictionary *item = [Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"text"];

    [item setObject:cell forKey:@"StrainTableCell"];
    BOOL checked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];

    NSLog(@"%i",checked);
    UIImage *image = (checked) ? [UIImage   imageNamed:@"checked.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    button.frame = frame;
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.accessoryView = button;

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Why are you adding a cell to the dictionary in the first place? Since cells get recycled, I think this is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the compiler is giving you a pretty good hint about what's going on: `mutating method sent to immutable object`. 
Even though you're declaring item as a `NSMutableDictionary` it doesn't mean that the object you're getting from `[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` is in fact a mutable dictionary.

Even if you do something like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

//the following line does not convert dict1 into a mutable dictionary
NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = (NSMutableDictionary*)dict1;
```

To solve this issue make sure the objects you add to `Strains` are mutable dictionaries. You could do this by directly instantiating one or by calling the `mutableCopy` method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm that's so odd. I use this same code on another set of View Controllers, and it works fine...? I'm wondering if I'm just missing something that the other VCs have...